# Why is my dog peeing in the house when I am home?

Tags: dogs, toilet-training, psychology

Why is my dog peeing in the house when I am home, but does not pee for 10 hours when he is confined to one room?
He is a 7 lb chihuahua mixed rescue, who lived with 70 other dogs, well, 69, and I have had him for 5 months now.
If I confine him to one room, with my other dog, he holds it all day. If I am home and I do not confine him, he is peeing, but I don't know when, I just find the old stains that are dried up already.

Comment: I under stand your problem. My girl is 6 I got her at 5 trained her for potty patch and to go outside. She only pees when I am in the office working and I take her out every 2 hours. Have 2 other toy poodle, and do not give any attention when I am working. she will use potty patch if I am gone (put all 3 in kitchen) sleeps through the night, 8 to 10 hours. I now have her in diaper when I am in the office, take it off when I leave and when going to bed. I am at a loss. She is such a sweet girl, no other problems

Answer (score 4):

He is not properly house-trained. You need to treat him like a puppy and start from the beginning. I am currently house-training a young puppy, and here is what I am doing:

If I cannot watch the puppy, she is in her crate. When she is inside the house and not in her crate, I have her tethered to me or to a piece of furniture very close to me with a 6-foot (2 meter) or shorter leash. I keep an eye on her, but I have found that I don't need to watch her every move when she is confined this way. I take her outside immediately after she wakes up or finishes eating, or after an hour has passed. (For an older dog, this time period could be longer). If she eliminates, I give her lots of praise and a treat. I also use a command "Go pee" when I see she is about to do it. If she does not eliminate within 5 minutes, she goes into her crate for 15 minutes, and then we try again. If I catch her starting to squat inside, I say "ah ah ah NO!" loudly as I immediately pick her up and take her outside. This is all aimed at teaching her it is good to go outside, and bad to do it inside.

It is extremely important that you clean up old accidents with an enzymatic cleaner which eliminates odors. Dogs will return to the scent of previous eliminations. Finally, if your dog has a favorite room to sneak off to, make that inaccessible by closing the door or using a baby gate.

This sounds like a lot of work, and it is. But your reward is a lifetime of reliable housetraining for a few months work.

Comment: I like your answer as it addresses the actual facts and doesn't try to elaborate on the "psychology" of the thing!